# html dl, dt and dd tags for generating a list

Tags: html, html-lists

Does anyone use the DL, DT and DD tags? I have a list with each item having a title and description and was wondering if this would be the best thing to use for it or would the simple ul and li tags be better?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a **definition list** (`<dl>`) is specifically for lists where each item has a title and description. You can then style the 'definition term' (AKA title `<dt>`) and description (`<dd>`) separately. Your markup will make more sense semantically, and also be more easily machine-readable. Definition lists have been part of HTML for as long as I can recall. Here's a [plain example](http://www.ecoconsulting.co.uk/training/), and a [fancier one with images](http://martin-richardson.com/publications.html), both using `<dl>`.

Answer (score 1):

I have used them on occasion. The scenario you describe, items with an title and a description, seems like an excellent candidate for the `DL` element. It's what the element is made for.

The [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html) says:

> Definition lists, created using the DL
>   element, generally consist of a series
>   of term/definition pairs (although
>   definition lists may have other
>   applications).

Additionally, you can use CSS to customize the appearance of your text.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a series of items with descriptions, I'd say that fits into the area of a definition list.

I don't use them personally, purely out of habit to be honest, I probably should though when they're the right thing to use.

Go on, live on the edge, go for it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Personally i always use UL and LI and never new DL, DT and DD tags existed until a while back when i was experimenting with HTML5. But when working with descriptions maybe DL, DT and DD is better.

Answer (score 0):

From a structuration point of view, DL, DT, DD tags are more appropriate for your need. Moreover you can style your specific lists independently from other UL, OL, LI lists without bothering with classes.